# can't use a variable extracted from $0 in path to source file

Tags: shell, grep, ksh

I'm trying to use the path of the current script to determine the location of the source script
ex:

```
export tenv=$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

If I hardcode **tenv** to the specific value I want, it works. Also if I call the same grep command to set **tenv** after sourcing the globalProfile, it works. But the above code doesn't work for some reason.

I'm running this script through a third party tool (AutoSys) which complicates the debugging process.  The goal is to extract "stage" from the root of the script path "/stage/myproject/scripts/testScript"

If I do this:

```
export tenv=stage
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

The job runs successfully, and I can see the output in the logs.

If I do this:

```
export tenv=$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
echo $0
echo "tenv: ${tenv}"
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

The job fails and no logs are produced.

If I do this:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
export tenv=$(echo $DIR | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
export alt=$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
echo $0
echo "DIR: ${DIR}"
echo "tenv: ${tenv}"
echo "alt: ${alt}"
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

The job fails, but it produces a log file containing the following:

```
/stage/myproject/scripts/testScript
DIR: /mnt/auto/home/myproject
tenv: mnt
alt: stage
```

So in this case, tenv got set to the wrong value and thus the overall job was a failue, but since we now have a log file, it shows that our original code (now stored in the alt variable) SHOULD have produced the right value.

For one final bit of insanity, if I do this:

```
export tenv=mnt
export alt=$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
echo $0
echo "tenv: ${tenv}"
echo "alt: ${alt}"
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

The job fails, and once again does not produce any logs, even though I explicitly set the tenv variable to the same value it used in the previous test.

Comment: I can, unfortunately in the context(autosys) I'm running this, the config  of the standard output logs is setup in the source script. So anything echoed prior to that is lost.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-to-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself/246128#246128

Comment: This is bizarre. Using that I can actually read the log. But the directory is wrong. However $0 does give me the correct directory which is "/stage/myproject/scripts/testScript", whereas echo DIR give me "/mnt/auto/home/myproject" what I need is "stage". The above code gives me "mnt". But as soon as I change $DIR back to $0, not only does it not work, but I can't read logs anymore

Comment: @Philippe Please see my update

Comment: The code looks fine; perhaps there is something in your environment or filesystem. Try breaking it down and simplifying. Try making an independent script that prints to stdout instead of a log, and put the script in different directories and invoke it in different ways. It's looking like /stage is a soft link to /mnt/auto/home. This shouldn't make a difference, it doesn't on my system, but maybe it does on yours.

Comment: Looks like your third run worked for the variable `alt`. Why not substitute `alt` for `tenv` in the final invocation of `globalProfile` and see if it works?

Comment: @eewanco That was the second run.  `alt` in the third run is just a rename of what `tenv` was in the second run.  So that doesn't work (even, though all reason seems to say it should).  Also, as mentioned this script is not being run from a command line, its being run by a third party tool (AutoSys), so I don't have access to a console to view stdout.  However the tools logs should be capturing stdout.

Comment: @yoyobroccoli Do you have access to an interactive shell, or only this logged batch job-thingy?

Comment: @eewanco Not as far as I know unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

I say try this:

```sh
. /$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

See how that goes. If it doesn't, perhaps you can further debug by temporarily changing
`. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile` to `. /stage/common/scripts/globalProfile` until you get it to work.

Comment: Tried that.  Didn't work.  And the original script had the `tenv` value hardcoded.  The whole goal of what I'm working on is to adapt theses scripts to get the environment name from the script path, so we don't need to duplicate scripts that are identical except for one hardcoded value.

Comment: I see -- I didn't realize that `tenv` was essential for something other than determining the location of the script; it's important to AutoSys and to the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you saw seems to be related to symbolic links in some paths.

Try this :

```
DIR="$( ""cd -L "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
export tenv=$(echo $DIR | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
export alt=$(echo $0 | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
echo $0 "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
echo "DIR: ${DIR}"
echo "tenv: ${tenv}"
echo "alt: ${alt}"
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

Only the first line is different from the extract in your post.

Comment: The above code result in the job fails and produces the following output: `/stage/myproject/scripts/script 
DIR: /mnt/auto/home/myproject 
tenv: mnt 
alt: stage`
And as soon as I replace the last line of the above code with . `/${alt}/common/scripts/globalProfile`  the job fails and no standard output was produced. I just can't make sense of it why `alt` is set to the correct value but once it was plugged in to the source file path, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I finally get it working by using a different way of getting the path

```
THIS=`readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 2>/dev/null||echo $0`
DIR=`dirname "${THIS}"`
export tenv=$(echo $DIR | grep -Pio "(?<=/)\w+" | head -1)
. /${tenv}/common/scripts/globalProfile
```

But I still don't get why readlink works while the other ones I have tried in the original post doesn't...